# Multiline search with perl

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I've tried a lot of solution found here but I still can't make Perl search on several line.

I've got a `index.htm` file with inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
         
    
         
      
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">  


    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/company/rses/14rwer/contents/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
 

<h2 class="subhead">
<p>principal facts:</p>
....
```

So I want to delete everything beginning with `<!DOCTYPE>` until the element `<h2 class="subhead"`.

I've tried with the `m` option like this (Isn't `m` for "multiline"?):

`find . -type f -name "index.htm" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/<\!DOCTYPE html>.*?<h2 class="subhead//mg'`

then with the `s` option...

but I still can't get this multiline selection.

I can get a ONE line selection like this:
`find . -type f -name "index.htm" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/<\!DOCTYPE html>//mg'`
but that's not what I want since I want to search and replace all these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/m` modifier changes how `^` and `$` behave in regular expressions (under multiline, they match at each line's start/end), the `/s` changes how `.` behaves (normally, `.` doesn't match a newline, but under `/s` it does).

But `perl -p` reads the input line by line, so the code is never executed for the whole input as a single string. use `-0777` to read the whole file as a single string:

```
perl -0777  -pe 's/<\!DOCTYPE html>.*?<h2 class="subhead">//sg'
```